# failed to idle channel

Tags: 14.04

I run ubuntu 14.04 on a acer aspire 5742g and for some reason after a while my screen goes black and i get this error messages:

```
Jul  2 21:01:44 steven-pc kernel: [ 1591.975086] nouveau E[Xorg[1078]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[1078]]
Jul  2 21:01:44 steven-pc kernel: [ 1592.066902] nouveau E[Xorg[1078]] failed to idle channel 0xcccc0000 [Xorg[1078]]
Jul  2 21:01:46 steven-pc kernel: [ 1594.066097] nouveau E[   PFIFO][0000:01:00.0] channel 2 [Xorg[1078]] kick timeout
```

i found the error log in : /var/log/kern.log
So far i know i haven't made any change to the kernel. Does anyone any idea what is wrong? if more information is required let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I had the same problem since I installed Ubuntu 14.04.

I run:
Ubuntu 14.04
Gigabyte motherboard
Core i7 920
GeForce GTX 275 (Nvidia GT200b)
12GB RAM
256G SSD

I resolved the problem by just changing the cable between the video card and the monitor from DVI cable to VGA cable. The video card has VGA, DVI, and HDMI outputs. For some reason, using the DVI port and cable to the monitor kept causing that "nouveau E Xorg failed to connect to idle channel 0xcccc0000" error.

Comment: I did something to fix it, thank you :) the problem is, replacing a DVI cable in a laptop sounds like a bad idea